# Managed Entity Framework not generating stored procedures mappings

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

Please note that I am attempting to use stored procedures to insert and update table records.  When I add the stored procedure to the database and update the *.edmx file, it sees the stored procedure I've added; however, I previously did the following with a different project:

```
var db = new MyMarinaEntities();
db.prBoatInsert(registrationNumber, manufacturer, modelYear, length, customerID);
```

Now, however, when I type "db." intellisense doesn't see the insert stored procedures.  Also, when I search in the InlandMarinaEntities.Designer.cs file, it doesn't have any

```
public int prBoatUpdate(Nullable<global::System.Int32> boatID, global::System.String registrationNumber, global::System.String manufacturer, Nullable<global::System.Int32> modelYear, Nullable<global::System.Int32> length, Nullable<global::System.Int32> customerID)
```

function.  Does anyone have any idea as to why it is not adding prBoatUpdate to the *.Designer.cs file?

Alternatively, I understand that MEF can generate Insert, Update and Delete operations for each table; however, when I generate the *.edmx file, I don't see any of these operations added, and I don't see any option to add them when going through the wizard to generate the *.edmx file.  What am I missing?  Please note that I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.  TIA.

Comment: MEF is the Managed Extensibility Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I determined how to add and update database items using the MEF auto-generated functions instead of using stored procedures.  Here is how you load an object from the database:

```
private void LoadBoat(int boatID)
{
    using (var db = new MyMarinaEntities())
    {
        var boat = db.Boats.SingleOrDefault(b => (b.BoatID == boatID));

        this.chkIsRental.Checked = boat.IsRental;
        this.chkInactive.Checked = boat.Inactive;
        this.txtLength.Text = boat.Length;
        this.txtManufacturer = boat.Manufacturer;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is how to save changes to the boat:

```
protected void btnSave_click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    using (var dm = new MyMarinaEntities())
    {
        MyMarinaEntities boat;

        boat.IsRental = this.chkIsRental.Checked;
        boat.Inactive = this.chkInactive.Checked;
        boat.Length = this.txtLength.Text;
        boat.Manufacturer = this.txtManufacturer;
        // ...
        if (boatID.Value == "") 
            dm.AddObject("Boats", boat);
        dm.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

So MEF not only saves you from writing lots of code for Object Relational Mapping (ORM), it also saves you from writing SQL code for stored procedures or commands.